# edge.foreach in not a function for vis DataView

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, vis.js

I am using vis to display some graph on my web.
I can use this piece of code to display :

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Network, DataSet, DataView} from 'vis';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']

})
export class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('network', {static: false}) el: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('nodeFilterSelect', {static:false}) nodeFilter: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('edgesFilter', {static: false}) edgeFilter: ElementRef;
  private networkInstance: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const nodes_set = new DataSet<any>([
      { id: 1, label: 'Eric Cartman', age: 'kid', gender: 'male' },
      { id: 2, label: 'Stan Marsh', age: 'kid', gender: 'male' },
      { id: 3, label: 'Wendy Testaburger', age: 'kid', gender: 'female' },
      { id: 4, label: 'Mr Mackey', age: 'adult', gender: 'male' },
      { id: 5, label: 'Sharon Marsh', age: 'adult', gender: 'female' }
  ],{});

  const edges_set = new DataSet<any>([
      { from: 1, to: 2, relation: 'friend', arrows: 'to, from', color: { color: 'red'} },
      { from: 1, to: 3, relation: 'friend', arrows: 'to, from', color: { color: 'red'} },
      { from: 2, to: 3, relation: 'friend', arrows: 'to, from', color: { color: 'red'} },
      { from: 5, to: 2, relation: 'parent', arrows: 'to', color: { color: 'green'} },
      { from: 4, to: 1, relation: 'teacher', arrows: 'to', color: { color: 'blue'} },
      { from: 4, to: 2, relation: 'teacher', arrows: 'to', color: { color: 'blue'} },
      { from: 4, to: 3, relation: 'teacher', arrows: 'to', color: { color: 'blue'} },
  ],{});

    const container = this.el.nativeElement;
    // this.networkInstance = new Network(container, {nodes_set, edges_set}, {});
    // // this.startNetwork({ nodes: nodesView, edges: edgesView })

     const data = { nodes: nodes_set, edges: edges_set };

     this.networkInstance = new Network(container, data, {});

  }
}
```

it works.

But now I wanna to use DataView in vis to do some filtering for the graph.
I added this to change DataSet to DataView:

```
const nodesView = new DataView(nodes_set, {})
const edgesView = new DataView(edges_set, {})
```

and use view data in Network:

```
     const data = { nodes: nodesView, edges: edgesView };

     this.networkInstance = new Network(container, data, {});
```

then I got this error:

> edgeData.forEach is not a function

```
AppComponent.ngfactory.js:30 ERROR TypeError: edgesData.forEach is not a function
    at EdgesHandler._addMissingEdges (vendor.js:157837)
    at EdgesHandler._updateState (vendor.js:157792)
    at Network.<anonymous> (vendor.js:152776)
    at Network.Emitter.emit (vendor.js:116593)
    at Network.setData (vendor.js:152837)
    at new Network (vendor.js:152622)
    at TestComponent.ngAfterViewInit (main.js:300)
    at callProviderLifecycles (vendor.js:64080)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (vendor.js:64045)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (vendor.js:64027)
```

I seems DataView didn't have the for each function?
Anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: I guess edgeData is not an array, can you provide the console log output for variable edgeData?

Comment: @YuchaoWu The variable edgeData is from vis library. I updated the web console. but for the output of edgeData, I cannot get it

Comment: Probably try to put the console log before the problematic forEach?

Comment: yes. But this forEach is in the library source code I installed, not in my code. All my code is shown above.  you can see no 'forEach' method called